# Python 3.9.7 terminating execution with no error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a recursive function that breaks the execution of the script unexpectedly but without any error messages.

This happens on Windows but it works fine on Ubuntu(wsl).

Could you tell me how I could make it work? Why is this happening?
This is the script:

```
import sys

N = 1542201487980564464479858919567403438179217763219681634914787749213
B = 100

def mod_pow(a, k, n):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    elif k % 2 == 0:
        return mod_pow(a, k // 2, n) ** 2 % n
    else:
        return (mod_pow(a, k - 1, n) * a) % n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
        N2 = N**9

        print('Calculated N2')
        a = mod_pow(23, N2, N)
        print("Try block finished correctly")
    except:
        print('something happened')
    finally:
        print('This is the finally block')
```

If I execute it on Windows (Python 3.9.7) it prints:

```
Calculated N2
```

On wsl-Ubuntu (Python 3.8.5) prints:

```
Calculated N2
Try block finished correctly
This is the finally block
```

Thanks

Comment: Same for me, interesting.. Doesn't answer your question, but if you need power-mod functionality, you can simply do `pow(a, b, modulo)`

Comment: "Could you tell me how I could make it work?" Well, why does the function need to be recursive in the first place? All the recursion does is adjust the values and try again - exactly one recursive call each time aside from the base cases, and no work after the call. That is fully [tail recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) and thus trivially convertible to iteration.

Comment: Also, yes, the specific functionality you are trying to implement is built in.

Comment: Thanks both for the comment! I have tried both alternatives and they work perfectly but I still feel like I need to find a way to make it work using a recursive function or at least a reason for the different results so I can know when to avoid recursion

Comment: And also I am just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

after comunicating the bug to the Python team,

they told me that the error comes probably from how Windows handles stack overflow exceptions.